# Is it possible to include Python and shell scripts in an npm package?

Tags: python, shell, npm

I have set up a GitHub repo called [npm2archOBS](https://github.com/fusion809/npm2archOBS) that is a fork of Filirom1's [npm2arch](https://github.com/Filirom1/npm2arch) repo. The only problem is that I have included Python and shell scripts in the [`bin`](https://github.com/fusion809/npm2archOBS/tree/master/bin) subdirectory of this repo (as my CoffeeScript / JavaScript knowledge is nowhere near up to the standard it would have to be in order to add the functionalities I want without using these two languages I am more familiar with). I know that when I run `sudo npm install -g .` locally and run the main command unique to my fork, `npm2OBS`, which is dependent on CoffeeScript, Python and shell components of my fork, it runs fine. I would like to add my fork to the NPM registry, but I suspect as there are Python and shell components to my fork there will be some issue, like with dependencies. I have heard of the [`python-shell`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) NPM package, that I potentially could use to overcome the Python component to this dependency issue.

The modules I require for my Python scripts to work are:

- `json`
- `subprocess`
- `sys`

if this is relevant. As far as the Unix shell I need my shell scripts to be able to use, in order for them to work, it is Bash.

I am essentially asking two things:

- Will my package be acceptable with Python and shell components in it as it is now?
- If not, what changes, if any, will fix this problem?

Comment: Actually your npm package & npm2arch are both doing wrong. Npm is for distribution of node packages in an OS agnostic way, since nodejs is multi-platform. You can not expect a present python in system, most windows has lack of it. More over Fedora and variants comes with python3 default. so you are trying to distribute a software only for Arch linux. so it should be in AUR not npm.